# Problema al desplegar Proyecto ASP.Net en Centos

Tags: asp.net, linux, nginx, mono

Buen día, quiero desplegar una solución construida en ASPnet, el desarrollo se hizo en WindowsSO/IIS, sobre un Sistema Operativo Centos usando como servidor Web NginX.

Estoy usando Centos-6.8, Nginx-1.10 y mono-4.6.1.5.

Mi archivo de configuración de nginx es:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #root /usr/share/nginx/html/Site;        

    location / {
        index index.aspx index.html index.htm index.aspx default.aspx Default.aspx Global.asax;
        fastcgi_index Global.asax;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
   ...
}
```

En el archivo fastcgi_params incluyo:

```
 fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          "";
 fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Y posteriormente inicio el servicio de Mono

```
fastcgi-mono-server4 /applications=/:/usr/share/nginx/html /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000 &
```

Al acceder a  http://localhost/Default.aspx para hacer pruebas si muestra resultado.

Cuando invoco la solución a través http://localhost/Site/ es donde tengo problemas, muestra el siguiente mensaje:

```
System.Web.HttpException
This type of page is not served.

Description: HTTP 403.The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden. The extension '.asax' may be incorrect. Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
Details: Requested URL: /Site/Global.asax
Exception stack trace:
  at System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00073] in <d3ba84a338d241e2ab5397407351c9cd>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () [0x00dd7] in <d3ba84a338d241e2ab5397407351c9cd>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () [0x00000] in <d3ba84a338d241e2ab5397407351c9cd>:0
```

Asigne permisos al usuario nginx sobre la carpeta Site que es donde tengo la solución, tal vez falta agregar alguna dependencia en el Web.Config de la aplicación, alguna idea?

Gracias.

Comment: Para los interesados, tuvimos que cambiar de Plataforma de desarrollo a [dotnet](https://dotnet.github.io/) y finalmente se pudo desplegar sobre Centos.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error se produce porque has configurado el archivo `Global.asax` como página de inicio y nginx lo está intentando ejecutar como si fuese una página.

Probablemente se solucione cambiando la configuración del bloque `location` por:

```
location / {
    index index.aspx index.html index.htm index.aspx default.aspx Default.aspx;
    fastcgi_index Default.aspx;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

**Actualización**: si el proyecto no incluyeun archivo `Default.aspx` (por ejemplo en un proyecto MVC puro), en la opción `fastcgi_index` hay que poner `/` para hacer referencia a la raiz, y la opción `index` se podría quitar.

La configuración quedaría así:

```
location / {
    fastcgi_index /;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Y según comentaba [fredyfx](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/822/fredyfx) en su respuesta, para acceder a la aplicación con  http://localhost/Site/ habría que añadir otro `location` *(en este caso creo que el valor de `fastcgi_index`sería el mismo pero no estoy seguro)*

```
location /Site {
    fastcgi_index /;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Gracias. Pero la solución no tiene un archivo Default.aspx, tiene Global.asax, este archivo contiene: <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="VRS.WebApp4.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

Comment: Hola @jorgedison, he actualizado la respuesta, espero que te funcione que no lo he probado. Saludos

Comment: Hola @rsciriano en efecto es un proyecto MVC puro, haciendo las modificaciones indicadas muestra el estado 404, no encuentra al parecer la ruta que por default tengo en el archivo web.config de la solucion. `<authentication mode="Windows"><forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" /></authentication>`. Gracias.

Comment: Hola @jorgedison podría ser que la opción `root /usr/share/nginx/html;` que no está apuntando al directorio de tu proyecto

Answer (score 0):

Agrega nueva "location":

```
location /Site {
        index index.aspx index.html index.htm index.aspx default.aspx Default.aspx Global.asax;
        fastcgi_index Global.asax;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: Gracias @fredyfx. Agregando otro location me sigue saliendo el mismo error: "..The extension '.asax' may be incorrect" la solución es compilada en un SO windows, seguire investigando.

Comment: Borra el Global.asax

Comment: De nada hermano :D